# Delay IIS until all Windows services are completely initialized

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, services, iis

I have some Windows services that are used by the Web services.

After a host reboot, Web Services are available before the Windows services are done initializing.

Is there a way to delay the IIS to at least not be accessible for X amount of time after reboot? Or to wait till the Windows services are up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the IIS service **Automatic (Delayed Start)**, Then this kind of services will start after all the **Automatic** services have been started.

we can do this services.msc:

1.open the **services.msc** as administrator
2.find the service **World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3svc)**
3.set it as **Automatic (Delayed Start)** (or just set it as Manual)
4.reboot the machine